# DAX error: The CurrentCatalog XML/A property was not specified

Tags: dax

I'm trying to run an EVALUATE query but keep getting this error:

```
The CurrentCatalog XML/A property was not specified.
```

What causes this error?

What's a `CurrentCatalog`'s XML/A property?

How can I fix this error?

---

Here are some details that I'm including in case they're relevant:

When I connect to the database server from DaxStudio it says `No Databases were found when connecting to [my-server\string]` but it still lets me execute the query. When connecting from SSMS there's no error, only the `CurrentCatalog` one.

Answer (score 0):

Did you provide correct Catalog (ModelName):

Here in DaxStudio:

[image]

```
Provider=MSOLAP.8;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=**YourModelName**;Data Source=YourServerName;MDX Compatibility=1;Safety Options=2;MDX Missing Member Mode=Error;Application Name=Microsoft Excel;App=Microsoft Excel;Update Isolation Level=2
```